# Updating database with multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, records

We use `SQL Server` and have `Winforms` application. In our product, sometimes the records exceeds more than 50000 in single transaction and we face Performance issue there.

When we have huge amount of data, we generally do that in multiple database calls. So in one of our Import functionality we are updating servers in a bunch of 1000 rows. So if we have 5000 records, then while processing them (in a for loop) we update the first 1000 rows and then continue processing until we get new 1000 rows to update. This performs better but honestly not the best I feel in terms of performance.

But we have seen in other Import/Export functionality that updating database with every 5000 rows is giving good results when compared to 1000. So there is a lot of confusion we are facing and also code does not look to be same across our applications.

Can anyone give me an idea what makes this happen. You don't have sample data, database schema etc. and yes I do agree. But are there any scenarios which should be taken care/considered while working with database? And why different number of records are giving us the good results, is there something we are ignoring? I am not a champ in database and more of a programming guy in .Net. Will be happy to hear your suggestions.

Not sure if this is helpful, our data generally contains employee details like payroll information, personal details, Accrual Benefits, Compensation etc. Data is fed from an excel and also we generate lot of data in our internal process. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!!

Comment: you have to add more information. do you perform 1000 single updates or do you update 1000 rows with one statement? or do you insert the 1000 rows in a temp table and then update the other table? To improve performance in general, avoid subselects and multiple ORs in your query, improve your keys and index, disable triggers, or do a bulk insert if possible

Answer (score 0):

The more database callouts you have, the more connection management you will need (open connection, use connection, cleanup & close, are we using connection pooling etc.etc.). You're sending the same amount of data over the wire, but you are opening and closing the taps more often, which brings overhead.

The downside of this is that the amount of data held in a transaction is greater.

However, if I may make a suggestion, you might want to consider achieving this in a different way, by loading all data into the database as fast as possible (into interim tables where the **contraints** are deativated and with transactional management turned off, if possible) and then allowing the database to carry out the task of checking and validating the data.

Since you are using SQL Server, you can just turn on SQL Profiler, define an appropriate event filter, and watch what happens under different loads.